# roles with ion auth or Community Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, roles, cas

I run the lastest version of Codeigniter 3 and I would like to use either one of these two authentication libraries:

Ion Auth (http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)
Community Auth (http://community-auth.com/)

BUT,

**Not interested in the auth part** because I the authentication process is handled by my company (we use CAS auth) so I only need the **roles functions** of these two libraries.

I'm thinking of something like this:

1. Launch the CAS auth function which returns a username that has been loogged in. (done)
2. Store this username to a session variable (done)
3. We have a SQL table with all the usernames and their respective roles (admin, superadmin, std user, etc) (done)
4. Each role has different access privileges to different parts of the website
   *5. HOW do I implement these roles/privileges in my codeigniter code? In the controller? Could these two libraries help me out with the access privileges? Any example on how to do this?*
5. Last but not least, I do not understand why CI does not provide built-in functions for handling roles as it seems to be a basic feature of any web application.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ion Auth provides you those functionality.
when You create an **user**, assign each user to any group.let say you have a group called **members**.
And then You can simply check your user group  by

```
$group ='members'

    if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group($group)){
// your code here
       }
```

You can use documentation and can modify as required.
thank you